# Ubuntu Server kernel does not upgrade

Tags: server, upgrade, kernel, updates

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04. If I run:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

It says I have the following kernels:

```
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic         4.15.0-20.21
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-22-generic         4.15.0-22.24
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-23-generic         4.15.0-23.25
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-24-generic         4.15.0-24.26
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic         4.15.0-29.31
```

However, if I check the current kernel version with:

```
uname -r
```

It says I'm using:

```
4.15.0-24-generic
```

So, how do I update the kernel to 4.15.0-29? I've tried:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

But it says there are no updates available.

Comment: What are the results of `sudo apt list --upgradeable` ? If the results include 4.15.0-29 kernel then `sudo apt upgrade` will upgrade to it.

Comment: No updates. It says: `Listing... Done`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This output

```
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic         4.15.0-29.31
```

means that the package `linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic` is *removed* (`r`) but the *configurations files* are still installed (`c`).

It was probably removed manually so `apt-get` won't reinstall it on upgrade.

You can simply do

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic
```

to re-install it, or better try reinstalling the `linux-image-generic` package which depends on the most recent kernel:

```
apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic
```

Comment: I did that and it installed version 4.15.0-33. Thank you!